# Java OutOfMemoryError with ArrayList<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist, out-of-memory

I want to create a very large graph (with ~10 million edges) in Java. I plan to `List<List<Integer>>` to describe the edges, with the inside `List<Integer>` describing the two vertices of each edge (and the vertices are Integer type).

The following code throws the `OutOfMemoryError` after about 1 million edges are added to the graph. (I simplified how the edge is generated for the sake of discussion.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    List<Integer> edge = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // the real edges are more complicated (than from vertex i to vertex i+1)
    // this is simplified for the sake of the discussion here
    edge.add(i);
    edge.add(i+1);
    graph.add(edge);
  }
}
```

I have searched for `OutOfMemoryError`, and I have increased the initial heap size to 2G for Eclipse: `-Xms2g -Xmx4g -Xss2m` (which get passed to JVM). But that did not solve the problem.

Then I thought maybe I should garbage collect the `List<Integer> edge` variable, by calling `System.gc()`, in case its memory does not get cleared. That did not work either.

I was thinking maybe the problem is with the `List<List<Integer>>` data structure. I tried `List<int[]>`, which lasted a bit longer: more edges are added before `OutOfMemoryError` happens. I do not have a better idea right now.

I have searched around for similar problems, but have not find much help. I wonder if anyone has experience with this kind of situation.

Comment: What about creating a class edge with only two int field?

Comment: No the parameters you set for eclipse does not get passed to the program inside

Comment: Check the Eclipse launch configuration, Arguments tab, VM arguments text box; use an appropriate -Xmx argument there.  Probably your jvm is being launched with the default limit, which is often 256MB.  Also please look what's going on in your post with less-than and greater-than characters because it sure doesn't look right.

Comment: @chrislott, thank you for your comment about the VM argument in run config. I think by "less-than and greater-than characters" you are referring to the angle brackets for the generics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To let your program use more memory from Eclipse:

Go to Run -> Run Configurations. You will see this window
[image: Run Configurations]

Click on Arguments
[image: Run Configurations/Arguments]

Enter your arguments to the VM
[image: Run Configurations/Arguments/VM Arguments]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a lot of RAM besides setting the max heap parameter, make sure you use 64-bit Java. The 32-bit is limited to 2 Gigs or something like that.

Also, for large graphs you should consider using a database.

And last but not least, maybe you can rethink your algorithm, sometimes you just don't need all the nodes and edges.